# Volley taking too long time to process the request

Tags: android

My Android application has event creation task. It sends image by encoding in basr64 format with event name, event location, event type, event start date and time, event end date and time, event category, event fee, event description, event cost, maximum participant number as parameter to request. Its taking too long almost >15 second. Client requirements is that it should process within 5 seconds. Can anyone help me to achieve this? Or any technique to speed up volley request processing. IOS responding faster than android.

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("eventname", etEventName.getText().toString().trim());
    params.put("userid", uid);
    params.put("lattitude", Double.toString(lat));
    params.put("longitude", Double.toString(longi));
    params.put("description", etEventDescription.getText().toString().trim());
    params.put("address", etEventLocation.getText().toString().trim());
    params.put("city", city);
    params.put("province", pro.trim());
    params.put("catid", caData);
    params.put("attendees", etEventPartcipentNumber.getText().toString().trim());
    params.put("startdate", startDate);
    params.put("starttime", starTime);
    params.put("enddate", endDate);
    params.put("endtime", endTime);
    params.put("eventtype", eventType);
    if (etEventFees.getText().toString().equals("") || etEventFees.getText().toString().equals(Fee)) {
        params.put("eventfee", "");
    } else {
        params.put("eventfee", etEventFees.getText().toString().substring(2).trim());
    }

    params.put("dayofweek", day);
    params.put("isprivate", privacy);
    params.put("profilepic", EventImage);
    params.put("myJid",mJid);
    params.put("openfirePsw",mPass);
    params.put("securityid", "MT0001");
    CustomeRequest create_eventRequest = new CustomeRequest(Request.Method.POST, urlCreateEvent, params, this.createeventSuccessResponseListener(), this.createeventErrorResponseListener());
    create_eventRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(create_eventRequest);




public class CustomeRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {

private Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener;
private Map<String,String> params;

public CustomeRequest(String url,Map<String,String> params,Response.Listener<JSONObject> responseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(Method.GET,url, errorListener);
    this.listener=responseListener;
    this.params=params;
}

public CustomeRequest(int method, String url,Map<String, String> params,Response.Listener<JSONObject> responseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, errorListener);
    this.params=params;
    this.listener=responseListener;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String,String> header=new HashMap<>();
    header.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return header;
}

@Override
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

    try {
        String jsonString=new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));

    } catch (JSONException je) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));

    }

}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
    listener.onResponse(response);
}
```

}

Comment: Uploading 300MB images base64 encoded has it's price indeed.

Comment: Post what you have tried so far